# Passing functions as arguments error: Cannot convert value of type "someType.type" to expected argument type "someType"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function, which takes several other functions as arguments:

```
class Iterator {
    func iterateItems(itemArray: [Items], removeItem: (Items) -> Void, addItem: (inout Items) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> [Items] {
        // function body
    }
}
```

And I call it in its class' subclass like this:

```
class WPCalculator: Iterator {

    func removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems) { ... }
    func addWeaponItem(item: inout WeaponItems) { ... }
    func calcWeaponDamage() { ... }

    func iterateWPItems() {
        iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems), addItem: addWeaponItem(item: &WeaponItems), calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage())
   }
}
```

Then Xcode says error on `removeItem` and `addItem` parameter:

> Cannot convert value of type "WeaponItems.type" to expected argument type "WeaponItems"

Also the `WeaponItems` class is a subclass of `Items` class:

```
class WeaponItems: Items { ... }
```

Why is that error message?

Comment: Are you able to produce more code? I cut and pasted the above source code into playground. There is not enough context. Maybe you should not name your variable `WeaponItems` in your invocation of removeItem and addItem the same as the class name `WeaponItems`.

Comment: There were some typos in the code, sorry for the confusion, I updated it. I'll see if I can add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a class `WeaponItems` instead of class objects. Following is more correct version:

```
func iterateWPItems() {
    let itemsToRemove = WeaponItems() //initialize object somehow
    var itemsToAdd = WeaponItems() //initialize object somehow
    iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem(item: itemsToRemove), addItem: addWeaponItem(item: &itemsToAdd), calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage())
}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I've got your problem. Than instead of **calling** these methods you should just **pass them as arguments**, so you don't have to put parentheses to a trail of method name:

```
func iterateWPItems() {
    iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem, addItem: addWeaponItem, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage)
}
```

Comment: I want to pass functions (`removeWeaponItem`, `addWeaponItem` and `calculateEfficiency`) as arguments so your propose answer is good but it's not the solution

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just realized it, thanks still!

Answer (score 0):

Within your invocation of iterateItems, `removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems)`, `WeaponItems` is a type, since it is the same as the class name `WeaponItems`. If you create variables of type WeaponItems, and name them differently (e.g., weaponItems) instead of WeaponItems, you probably will not run into this problem.

Comment: Did I create any variable named `WeaponItems`?

Comment: Observe the call to iterateItems:

func iterateWPItems() {
        iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems), addItem: addWeaponItem(item: &WeaponItems), calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage())
   }

Comment: There was a `WeaponItems.weaponItems`, it's a variable of class `WeaponItems`, not the class itself. BTW, there seems to be some more typos in my code, oops, I updated it again.

Comment: I think you mean the following:

iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems.weaponItems), addItem: addWeaponItem(item: &WeaponItems.weaponItems), calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage())

Comment: Nah not really it should be an instance of `WeaponItems` like `let item = WeaponItems()`

Comment: Kindly check your code before posting a question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the way I passed functions as arguments is wrong, it should be like this:

```
func iterateWPItems() {
    iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem as! (Items) -> Void, addItem: addWeaponItem as! (inout Items) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage())
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, and `calcWeaponDemage` shouldn't have parentheses at the end.